# Dynamic timetable android with unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, timetable

Hi I am looking for solution to make an application similar to [this one](http://appfellas.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/BKS-android-landscape-timetable.jpg).

The key part is that application is able to show current time as this red line on the screen, time bar, instead of number(one, two,...) there should be placed classrooms and  instead of rectangles with(for example this one with title "The Bots") with lectures titles. Also this should be scrollable(numbers up and down) and timetable in all directions(up,down,left,right).

I have done research last few days and didn't find anything that I could start with.
I am pretty new with android and I don't know how can I achieve this? I thought that this could be done with Unity or it can be achieved with something simpler? If it's possible to be done with unity, could you provide me with reference links?
Please help me to find the way out.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, if using android,

1. create a calendar view in day or week. Then, get and add those classrooms details timeslot into it.
2. Scrollable layout is going to used.
3. the red line can be done by using get current time function and draw a red line.